# Mongoose how to query an array of subdocuments with an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm setting up a new server, using mongoDB for the DB and mongoose to interact with it. I have links of images saved in the DB with tags, all the images have the common tag: `*` (which get retrieved and saved when saving a new image)
And I want to retrieve images with all the given tags.

Here is the schema for the images

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const imageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  link: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  tags: {
    type: [{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Tag'
    ]},
    default: []
  }
});

consy Image = mongoose.model('Image', imageSchema);
```

Here is the schema for the tags

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const tagSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
    maxlength: 20,
    lowercase: true
  }
});

const Tag = mongoose.model('Tag', tagSchema);
```

Here is what i have tried

```js
Image.find({
  tags: {
    $elemMatch: {
      name: { $in: ['*'] }
    }
  }
}).populate('tags');
```

and also

```js
Image.find({
  'tags.name': { $in: ['*'] }
}).populate('tags');
```

but I get no images.
But when I do a simple `Image.find().populate('tags');` I do get all the images with the property tags that is an array of objects, with for only one object a tag with for name: `*`.

What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To find the common tags we can use the [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/index.html). Please find the below query to retrieve all tags with `*`

```
Image.find({
  'tags.name': { $regex: /\*/, $options: 'i' } 
})
```

Comment: It doesn't work, no images get returned. And the number of tags to use for the query can vary, it's not always `*` so I need to use an operator to match an array

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to find all the images that have the `'*'` tag, perhaps you can try -

```
find().
populate({
  path: 'tags',
  match: { name: '*' }
}).
exec();
```

This link will be useful to you I think - https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions

Comment: the match in the populate function is to find the field you're trying to populate (in this case tags). your query will find _all_ the images and populate only the tags with for name `*`